# Bluemix Cloudant - Internal Server Error

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-mobile-services

I've been building an iOS app with Cloudant Sync on Bluemix. When I add a Cloudant service, I am able to read and write data to the database, and develop my app.

But three times now, when I've moved away from my computer and returned a few hours later, the Cloudant database shows 'Internal Server Error' when I launch the dashboard link from Bluemix.

If I delete the service and add a new one, refill the data, it works fine.

Until a few hours later.

I checked a couple of older Cloudant instances I had, and they showed 'Internal Server Error' too.

I'm not sure I can rely on this service. Please can someone advise?

Comment: What happens when you try accessing `_all_docs` via curl?

Answer (score 2):

We are currently experiencing some DNS-related problems with the Cloudant Dashboard when accessing it both for new and existing service instances. The Cloudant team is already working on a general fix for this issue. In the meanwhile, in order to get help for your instance, I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.